# Real-sky radiation with r.sun in GRASS: Why do atmospheric factors (e.g. cloudiness) reduce diffuse radiation?

Tags: grass-gis, solar-radiation

`r.sun` in GRASS ([enter link description here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.sun.html)) makes it possible to calculate real-sky radiation (as opposed to clear-sky) with the `coeff_bh` and `coeff_dh` parameters. The relevant part of the documentation is below. Suri and Hofierka (2004, section 3.2) discuss this in more detail.

> Besides clear-sky radiations, the user can compute a real-sky radiation (beam, diffuse) using coeff_bh and coeff_dh input raster maps defining the fraction of the respective clear-sky radiations reduced by atmospheric factors (e.g. cloudiness). The value is between 0-1. Usually these coefficients can be obtained from a long-terms meteorological measurements provided as raster maps with spatial distribution of these coefficients separately for beam and diffuse radiation (see Suri and Hofierka, 2004, section 3.2).

**Question**: Why does `r.sun` assumes that real-sky diffuse radiation is lower or equal to clear-sky diffuse radiation? The real-sky diffuse radiation coefficient  `coeff_dh` is supposed to be between 0 and 1 and defined as "the fraction of the respective clear-sky radiations reduced by atmospheric factors". Don't certain atmospheric factors such as thin clouds *increase* diffuse radiation?

For example, data from the National Solar Radiation Database ([enter link description here](https://nsrdb.nrel.gov)) for the northeastern United States indicates that the interquartile range for the ratio DHI/DHI_clearsky (DHI = diffuse horizontal irradiance) ranges from 1.0 to 1.4.